# "unresolved import" when using an item from a nested module

Tags: module, rust, visibility, rust-crates

I have a small program that I've been trying to get working, but I keep getting unresolved import messages.

main.rs:

```
mod sub_module;
use sub_module::a_structure;

fn main() {
    let x: a_structure = /* init code */;
}
```

sub_module.rs:

```
pub mod sub_sub_module;

pub use sub_sub_module::a_structure;
```

sub_sub_module.rs:

```
pub struct a_structure<T> {
    some_field: i32,
}
```

However, on executing `cargo build` I get an "unresolved import `sub_sub_module::a_structure`". Everything I've found regarding visibility says that this should work however it doesn't. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of Rust modules as being like a directory tree.  Modules are directories, everything else is a file [1].  `::` is basically `/`.

So, you have *this* structure:

```
/ (crate root)
 └┬─ sub_module
  │   └┬─ sub_sub_module
  │    │   └── a_structure
  │    └─ a_structure [x]
  ├─ a_structure
  └─ main
```

The problem is in how you define the `a_structure [x]` "symlink".  As explained in the book, [`use` paths in Rust are absolute](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html#re-exporting-with-pub-use), meaning in this analogy that they *all* implicitly start with `/`.  Meaning that `use sub_sub_module::a_structure` is referring to `/sub_sub_module/a_structure`, which *doesn't exist*.

The solution is to use a relative path by explicitly starting the path with `self` (effectively `.`) or `super` (effectively `..`).  You want `./sub_sub_module/a_structure`, so the path in Rust should be `self::sub_sub_module::a_structure`.  A full, compiling (with warnings) example looks like:

```rust
mod sub_module {
    pub mod sub_sub_module {
        pub struct a_structure {
            some_field: i32,
        }
    }

    pub use self::sub_sub_module::a_structure;
}

use sub_module::a_structure;

fn main() {
    let x: a_structure = panic!("TODO");
}
```

You should also note that paths used anywhere *outside* of a `use` have the exact opposite default: they are relative to the containing module by default.  If you *want* an absolute path in that case, you need to explicitly ask for one by starting the path with `::` (just like a filesystem path that is, by default, interpreted as relative).

*Aside*: The conventional style is to use `PascalCase` for type names.  Also, I had to remove the type parameter because it wasn't being used.

---

[1]: This is, in fact, a lie, as you can have items associated with *other* items.  For example, associated `const`s, while unstable, *are* a thing.  I suppose you could think of them in terms of resource forks or something, I don't know; it's just a metaphor!